# Sorting a list based on the length of each entry

Tags: lists, itemize, sorting

Is there a way to sort an itemized list based on the length of each item? Something like

```
\begin{Itemize}
\item a
\item aaaaaa
\item aaaa
\item aaa
\item aaaaa
\item aa
\end{Itemize}
```

which results in

> a
>   aa
>   aaa
>   aaaa
>   aaaaa
>   aaaaaa

Comment: what is you real use case? Do you have to use `\item` markup (which makes it harder as the items are not explicit arguments of anything, and what do you mean by "length" characters in the input or typeset length is `W` longer than `..` or not?

Comment: Sorry for delay in replying.  The answer you have provided in the following is precisely what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

This assumes you meant typeset length (and that all the items are single line)

```
\documentclass{article}


\def\Itemize{\vbox\bgroup
  \let\item\ItemizeItem
  \let\endItemizeItem\relax}

\def\ItemizeItem{%
  \endItemizeItem
  \let\endItemizeItem\xendItemizeItem
  \setbox0\hbox\bgroup\strut\ignorespaces}

\def\endItemize{\endItemizeItem\egroup}

\def\xendItemizeItem{%
  \unskip\egroup
  \setbox4\vbox{}%
  \loop
    \unskip
    \setbox2\lastbox
  \ifdim\wd2>\wd0
    \setbox4\vbox{\box2\unvbox4}%
  \repeat
  \nointerlineskip
  \box2
  \nointerlineskip
  \box0
  \unvbox4}



\begin{document}

\begin{Itemize}
\item a
\item aaaaaa
\item aaaa
\item aaa
\item aaaaa
\item aa
\end{Itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great technique! I'm doing a brain-internal right-click save!

Comment: Sorting items in a list can be very useful to avoid ugly lists.  It is nice to have a list with entries sorted according to the number of characters they have.  Of course, here the order of entries is not important.  Until now, I had to sort the list entries manually which is tedious and time consuming.  It will even be worse if at a later time you have to add new entries.  David's solution is a breath of fresh air.